# Executing another's Controller action

Tags: symfony

I have to deal with "measurement chains", each of which is composed of 1 measuring instrument and several tanks. Chains, Instruments and Tanks are in a Location.

Obviously, a Chain in a Location A cannot be composed of elements located in Location B or C.

So I have the following objects:

- CHAIN

  - chain_id
  - location_id
  - instrument_id
  - date_creation
  - date_destruction
- INSTRUMENT

  - instrument_id
  - location_id
- TANK

  - tank_id
  - location_id
- TANK_IN_CHAIN

  - tank_in_chain_id
  - tank_id
  - chain_id
  - date_connection
  - date_disconnection
- LOCATION

  - location_id

**What I want to do is:**

- When I move an Instrument in a new Location (moveAction() in InstrumentController), the chain should be detroyed
- When I move a Tank in a new Location (moveAction() in TankController), the chain should be detroyed
- "Destroying" a Chain means: chain.date_destruction set to now() and tank_in_chain.date_disconnection set to now() for all relevant tanks. This is done in the destroAction in ChainController (because sometimes I also need to destroy Chains even if no Instrument or Tank moved)

**My problem is:**

How do I call ChainController::destroyAction() from InstrumentController::moveAction() or TankController::moveAction()?

I read about the forward() function but from what I understood this is not what I need.
The other possibility I see is to set the ChainController as a service, but I'm not sure this is the proper way to solve this problem, i.e. it may work but this is not the "good practice".

What do you think?

Tanks for any help!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using forward method inside of a controller?

But for me, the right place to handle changes in an entity that could lead to a change in another entity is in Entity level. That means you should have some listener method in your entity to listen for a change of this entity, so that it could trigger a change of the related entity. In your case, I would have:

- A PostUpdate method on Instrument entity
- A PostUpdate method on Tank entity
- Then in each of this method, set date_destruction to now for the related Chain entity.

Take a look at Doctrine lifecycle callback http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: Thanks. The lifecycle callbacks seem to be too simple for my case (the example I gave is simplified for a better understanding), but reading the doc it seems that some "normal" Events could do the job the right way. I will investigate that.

Comment: Yes, I prefer using event listener in that case. And you could even tie it with services for the ease of testing :)

Comment: I managed to create Event and Listener to destroy a Chain when an Instrument or Tank is move. Now I'm trying to disconnect the Tanks when the Chain is distroyed by the above mentionned events. In other words, I want to trigger an event from an EventListener but the function get() in : $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(CoreEvents::onChainDestruction, $event); is not recognized outside a Controller. I found a lot of similar problems on the web, but it is still very unclear for me how to do it. Any idea?

Comment: Finally I put everything in the same Listener so I don't have to solve this problem for the moment :-D

Comment: Yeah, sounds good to me as long as it works :). But it's strange that the event is not recognized outside the controller. Have you tagged your listener as "kernel.event_listener" and registered it as a service?

Comment: Ahh, I see why you don't get the service in your EventListener. It's because you have to pass an instance of EventListenerInteface to your EventListener class. For example, when registering your EventListener, you should pass EventListenerInterface as an argument to the constructor so that you can make a call directly in your EventListener such as: $this->eventListener->dispatch(CoreEvents::onChainDestruction, $event);

Answer (score 0):

The good way for this is to defined your [controller as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw this possibility but in the Service Container Cookbook page, it is written that "a Service is any PHP object that performs some sort of global task" like mailling. Which is not really my case, this detroyAction() is not global: I don't want to access it from LocationController, for example. This is why I wondered if it was really the right way.